# How to create a voldemort store?

Tags: java, voldemort

I am trying to understand the Voldemort java API. I am new to non relational databases, so as I understand, Voldemort's store can be compared to a table in relational model. I saw the following code in the documentation.

```
String bootstrapUrl = "tcp://localhost:6666";
StoreClientFactory factory = new SocketStoreClientFactory(new ClientConfig().setBootstrapUrls(bootstrapUrl));

// create a client that executes operations on a single store
StoreClient client = factory.getStoreClient("test");
```

Here, we got a Store client based on the an existing store (test). How can I actually create a store for Voldemort through java?

Answer (score 0):

From what I've read, you can't.

This is because a `Store` is defined in the `stores.xml` file for the Voldemort Server and it isn't modifiable through the Java API.

It isn't modifiable because the `store` creation looks to be done on startup.

You can browse the Code here: https://github.com/voldemort/voldemort

Comment: well I think you can modify the store, but I wasn't able to find anything that actually creates it. I have not tried modifying the store, but it looks like the update method in StorageConfiguration interface is meant to modify it. Take a look here: http://www.project-voldemort.com/voldemort/javadoc/all/voldemort/store/StorageConfiguration.html

Comment: And I hope that the update method also creates one if not already there. Will post an answer if that works :)

Comment: You can create a store using the AdminClient object's addStore method